# Check if dtype of series belongs to a list of dtypes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series. I want to check if the dtype of the series is in a list of dtypes. Something like:

```
series.dtype not in [pd.dtype('float64'), pd.dtype('float32')]
```

This gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Sorry are testing all elements or the entire homogoneous series?

Comment: The entire homogeneous series. The dtype that pandas has associated with the whole series - just making sure I understand you correctly.

Comment: there is no such method/thing as `pd.dtype()` - there is `np.dtype()` or `pd.np.dtype()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use `dtypes` for checking if `Series` is not `float`:

```
print df
          a      b    c
0 -1.828219   True  1.0
1  0.681694  False  2.0
2 -2.360949   True  1.0
3  1.034397  False  2.0
4  1.073993   True  1.0
5  1.306872  False  2.0

print df.a.dtype
float32
print df.b.dtype
bool

print df.a.dtype not in [pd.np.dtype('float64'), pd.np.dtype('float32')] 
False           
print df.b.dtype not in [pd.np.dtype('float64'), pd.np.dtype('float32')] 
True
```

Works `np.dtype` too as mentioned [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284770/check-if-dtype-of-series-belongs-to-a-list-of-dtypes-in-pandas#comment60195608_36284770):

```
print df.a.dtype not in [np.dtype('float64'), np.dtype('float32')] 
False              
print df.b.dtype not in [np.dtype('float64'), np.dtype('float32')] 
True
```

Comment: I check docs and it is [`dtype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dtype.html). And you can check `type` one value of `Series` like `print type(df.at[0,'a'])`

Answer (score 1):

there is no such method/thing as `pd.dtype()` - there is `np.dtype()` or `pd.np.dtype()`:

```
In [86]: pd.dtype
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-dbe1c1048375> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.dtype

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'dtype'

In [87]: np.dtype
Out[87]: numpy.dtype

In [88]: pd.np.dtype
Out[88]: numpy.dtype
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and pass `include=['floating']`:

```
In [11]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'float':[0.0, 1.2, 5.5], 'int':[0,1,2], 'str':list('abc')})
df

Out[11]:
   float  int str
0    0.0    0   a
1    1.2    1   b
2    5.5    2   c

In [12]:
df.select_dtypes(include=['floating'])

Out[12]:
   float
0    0.0
1    1.2
2    5.5
```